# how to upload multiple multipart images through API in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am new to app development & still learning flutter, I used multiple image picker package to pick multiple images from gallery, I am wondering how can I post the list of images to to server using API? I am using MongoDB with AWS. any help is appreciated.

```
  Future<String> uploadImage(filename) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverReceiverPath));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', filename));
    var res = await request.send();
    print(res.statusCode);
    var bodyResponse = await res.stream.bytesToString(); // response body
    print(bodyResponse);
  }
```

Below is code to pick images from gallery using multi image picker, I am able to pick images and show them on the screen.

```
class PickImages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PickImagesState createState() => _PickImagesState();
}

class _PickImagesState extends State<PickImages> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
//  String _error = 'No Error Detected';


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No Error Dectected';

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 300,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Example App",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
//      _error = error;
    });
  }


    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            height: height(context)*0.35,
            width: 400,
            child: buildGridView()),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pick images"),
          onPressed: loadAssets,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```